# Find first of operation on a char pointer

Tags: c, char, eol

I have a char buffer which contains characters read from a file. I need to take this char buffer and find the first end of line character within it.

EOL characters in this case are \n,\r,\f.

Initially, I was planning to do the following:

```
// let's read into our buffer now...
char * m_pLineBuff;
if(!readCharBuf(m_pLineBuff, bytesToRead)) { report("Could not fill line buffer", RPT_ERROR, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }

// setup our newline candidates in an array
int iEOLChars[] = {'\n','\f','\r'};

// find the first instance of a newline character
int iEOLPosition = std::find_first_of(m_pLineBuff, m_pLineBuff+bytesToRead, iEOLChars, iEOLChars+3);
```

However, I apparently cannot pass a char pointer to the `std::find_first_of` method -- I can only pass an integer. The exact error the compiler provides me is:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘int’
```

This seems strange to me, as I've defined the start and end locations of my char buffer and I do not understand why it could not iterate through them looking for the first occurrence of any of my EOL characters.

Any advice on how to resolve this? Is there a way to use `find_first_of`, or should I simply iterate through each position of the char buffer and check to see if the char at the location matches any of my EOL characters.

The "find_first_of" function I am referring to is this one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/

Any assistance is always appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you pass a `char*` to `find_first_of`, what error do you get? If you don't say so, it makes people have to try to compile your code, and most people don't have the time. That could be the difference between an answer or not.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie Good point -- I've updated to include this information.

Comment: Why do people still use Hungarian Notation? :/

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I'm writing code here for an internship and the code styling requires hungarian notation. That said, I've found it quite useful throughout my internship and will likely continue to use it afterwards.

Comment: Ok...I got it from the answers.

/** Just out of curiosity, why can a `char *` be an iterator? The first two arguments are `char *` and last two are `int *` right? I am just a student trying to understand this stuff. An explanation will be highly appreciated...thanks. */

Comment: @mtahmed, I provide both the start and end bounds of the char * (char buffer in my case). Since we know the size of a char (sizeof(char)), we can iterate through the char buffer with these start and end bounds.

Comment: @mtahmed that's the beauty of templates. The STL was designed so that the operators `++`, `==`, `*`, `->` and `!=` could be used on iterators, and the template functions that take iterators use just those operators. Pointers use the same operators for the same operations, so when you use templates, the compiler figures it all out for you and you can use any type that supports those operators.

Comment: @BSchlinker: You might want to read articles why HN is bad (if you are more the tl;dr person: Especially in strongly-typed languages the IDE can tell you the type of a variable. Putting it in the name requires you to change many places if you change the type - and even if the IDE does that for you, it will still create unnecessarily large diffs and makes merge conflicts (depending on your VCS) more likely). Prefixing global and member variables is fine though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `find_first_of` returns, in this case, a pointer, not an index, so try:

```
char *iEOLPosition = std::find_first_of(m_pLineBuff, m_pLineBuff+bytesToRead, iEOLChars, iEOLChars+3);
```

Comment: Thank you. I really do appreciate the assistance -- I shouldn't have assumed it would return an integer index. My fault for using C++ strings and not enough char *.

Comment: And more generally the returns has the same type as the first two arguments.

Comment: @BSchlinker: Using C++ std::strings, if you can, is, IMO, much better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a type mismatch here:

```
char * m_pLineBuff;

int iEOLChars[] = {'\n','\f','\r'};
```

Try it declaring your `iEOLChars` as a `char` array.

Comment: This is the opposite of the issue -- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/ requires integers, not char*

Comment: @BSchlinker it's a template, how can it require integers? This answer is (I believe) correct. It becomes apparent if you look at the code on that page you linked.

Comment: I was passing it a char array previously, received the same error twice in that scenario.

Comment: It's a template, so it just requires that all parameters' types match. All int or all char, but all the same.

Comment: Did you change the type of the variable to which you assign the return value as well?

Comment: The return type was it -- I misunderstood your initial comment Antonio, I apologize.

Comment: find_first_of accepts 2 groups of 2 iterators and the iterators don't have to have the same type nor value type.

Comment: @AProgrammer: that's right, my previous comment is not accurate, you just need that the operator '==', or implicit conversion, for both value types exists.

Answer (score -1):

Check your first_first_of function I think it can never have 4 parameters
Refer [first_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/)

Comment: This would be true for the find_first_of for a string, but this is for a char *. See 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/

Comment: He is using std::find_first_of (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/), not std::string::find_first_of

Comment: Sorry my bad!! Should have seen properly before posting